# How to install a global npm package using fnm (Fast Node Manager)?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

**My Problem**
I have installed fnm (Fast Node Manager) from [this github repo](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm) and it works all great except for installing global npm packages. For example, the well-known package `nodemon` is something I want installed globally and not im my `node_modules` project directory.

When installing the package globally there seems to be no problem:
[image]

And when checking the global package list, `nodemon` seems to be there:
[image]

But when running the command `nodemon` I get the following output:
[image: Image of my terminal output error]

As also seen in the fnm [repository documentation](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm#bash) there is a need to run this piece of code `eval "$(fnm env --use-on-cd)";` on load in order to get fnm to work properly and this is what I have done in the `.bashrc` file.

**Note**
I am using windows 10, seems to be working on my mac laptop.

**The Question**
How can I have a global npm package installed for all or at least a single fnm node version? And what I mean by this, is that by running `fnm use <NODE_VERION>` you specify what  node version to use as also seen in the [repository documentation](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm#shell-setup). I want to be able to run the `nodemon` command without it being installed in a project's `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to delete the multishells. The problem is the Git Bash path.

Fix is here: https://github.com/Schniz/fnm/issues/390

Put this in your .bashrc

```
eval $(fnm env | sed 1d)
export PATH=$(cygpath $FNM_MULTISHELL_PATH):$PATH

if [[ -f .node-version || -f .nvmrc ]]; then
    fnm use
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! 
This did the trick for me.

https://github.com/Schniz/fnm/issues/390#issuecomment-776240883

Comment: Amazing, this is way better than the solution I provided, which was a work around.

Comment: worked for me in gitbash running in wezterm on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned this actually worked on my OS X machine (aka my mac book pro) but not on my windows 10 computer. The solution I came up with after analyzing thoroughly the behaviour of `fnm` is the following:

1. Go to `C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\AppData\Local\fnm_multishells` and delete the directory if it exists.
2. When downloading global packages do it via `CMD` or any terminal which isn't bash (or the terminal that has the `"$(fnm env --use-on-cd)";` script) as this makes fnm then search for the global package in the wrong place.

This approach mitigates any path errors as I found that this was the core problem. As shown in the screenshot above when trying to run `nodemon` it looks for it in `C:\Program Files\Git\Users\Valeri.....` but this directory simply does not exist. After removing the directory mentioned in step 1 `fnm` stops looking for `nodemon` in that path and instead uses the one installed via `CMD`.

Essentially, the `"$(fnm env --use-on-cd)";` script allows us to use fnm properly but at the same time causes this issue. Simply download global npm packages from a terminal that does not run this command.

**Edit**
I just had the same issue and to confirm you don't even need to delete the `fnm_multishells` directory. Just run `npm -g remove <whatever>` and install it via `cmd` or `powershell`. A command-line which does not run `"$(fnm env --use-on-cd)";` on load.